# Rounding of decimal number to whole number

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having a problem with the result of the average in my UserForm. So, I have 4 textboxes where the user will input the grades then upon clicking the button, it will get the average of it.

Here's my code:

```
Dim Total As Double, i As Integer
 
 If IsNumeric(tb_music) Then Total = Total + CDbl(tb_music): i = i + 1
 If IsNumeric(tb_arts) Then Total = Total + CDbl(tb_arts): i = i + 1
 If IsNumeric(tb_pe) Then Total = Total + CDbl(tb_pe): i = i + 1
 If IsNumeric(tb_health) Then Total = Total + CDbl(tb_health): i = i + 1
 
 tb_mapeh.value = Round(Total / i, 0)
```

I tried to input a grade of `88`, `91`, `92`, and `91`. When using a calculator, the result will be `90.5`, right? The result of my code above is `90`. I need to show the result as `91`. Can someone help me?

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Use `WorksheetFunction.Round` instead of `Round`. The latter uses bankers rounding, which is normally not what you want.

Comment: @BigBen it worked! Thanks!