# Round decimals to whole number

Tags: excel, vba

I'm just wondering how I can round off decimals to the nearest whole number. So the problem is that I'm using `Round(Total / i, 0)` code, but when the value is something like `.5` decimals, it doesn't round off.

Example: The value is 92.5, but the result only shows 92, not 93.

Comment: Use `WorksheetFunction.Round`. `Round` uses bankers rounding, as noted in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/round-function).

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize `Roundup()` function. For `VBA` try like-

```
Sub rUP()
Dim x As Double

    x = 92.5
    MsgBox Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(x, 0)
    
End Sub
```

Comment: That's not what OP wants though. For example, `92.3` would get rounded to `93`, not `92`. `WorksheetFunction.Round` seems like what OP wants: "to the nearest whole number"

Comment: @BigBen In that case your suggestion is correct. He need to use application Round function like `Application.WorksheetFunction.Round(x, 0)`

Comment: .... and strangely enough, it seems that OP asked [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67067347/rounding-of-decimal-number-to-whole-number) last month, which was also closed as a duplicate (by me).